# A SQL example that not works

Tags: sql

I wrote this code

```
select maker.product , product.type
from product
join laptop on laptop.model=product.model
join pc on pc.model=product.model
join printer on printer.model=product.model 
WHERE (product.type= 'pc' AND 
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker 
FROM Product
WHERE product.type = 'laptop'
))and (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker 
FROM Product
WHERE product.type = 'printer'  
))
or 
product.type= 'laptop' AND 
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker 
FROM Product
WHERE product.type= 'pc' 
))and (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker 
FROM Product
WHERE product.type= 'printer'
))
or
type = 'printer' AND 
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker 
FROM Product
WHERE product.type= 'laptop' 
))and (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker 
FROM Product
WHERE product.type= 'pc' 
)))
group by product.maker
having count(product.model) > 1
```

in this site  [sql-ex.ru](http://www.sql-ex.ru/) in exercise 14 but it  didn't work.
the question was :
For Product table, receive result set in the form of a table with columns: maker, pc, laptop, and printer.For each maker, this table must include "yes" if a maker has products of corresponding type or "no" otherwise.In the first case (yes), specify in brackets (without spaces) the quantity of available distinct models of corresponding type (i.e. being in PC, Laptop, and Printer tables).

And it's  Scheme is

[image: Scheme Picture]

Sorry for my bad English speaking !
Please help !
Thank you .

Comment: 1. Use a bit of indentation - Helps readability 2. What do you mean 'not works' 3. Why use fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ for a example to demonstration and also potential people to try an answer

Comment: I mean it doesn't return the currect result
And also thank you for introduce me that site

Comment: @ali - Sort out indentation - Sort out a fiddle - You might then get somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more readable version of your code (unless I've made a mistake):

```
select maker.product , product.type
from product
join laptop on laptop.model=product.model
join pc on pc.model=product.model
join printer on printer.model=product.model 
WHERE (
  product.type= 'pc' AND 
  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE product.type = 'laptop')) and
  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE product.type = 'printer'))
  or 
  product.type= 'laptop' AND 
  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE product.type= 'pc')) and
  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE product.type= 'printer'))
  or
  type = 'printer' AND 
  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE product.type= 'laptop')) and
  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE product.type= 'pc'))
)
group by product.maker
having count(product.model) > 1
```

Basically, it looks like you need to do parenthesis between each of the OR's.